# Check multiple ip addresses effciently against one address

Tags: java, regex, performance

I have a list of ip addresses as Strings, and an adress in String format to check agianst these adresses. My goal is to find whether my address is in the list or not. To make this situation difficult, these ip addresses not full adresses, but rather regular expressions. e.g. 10\.25\.3
What is the most efficient way to run hundreds of regex patters on a single String? Piping them? Search tree? A specific java container that can help me?
Do you have any suggestions?

Edit:
I can transform and store the list of addresses to anything before processing, this does not matter.

Comment: Are the IP addresses only *prefixes* or arbitrary wildcard strings?

Comment: It is a list of prefixes like:  
10\.25\.3  
108\.28\.4  
...

Comment: If your list of adresses indeed is a list of regular expressions, i would just try to match them against your string. You can just stop when you find a positive match.

Comment: But it is for an interceptor that intercepts thousands of requests per day. If i run all checks for all requests each time, it can hit performance, couldn't it?

Comment: Maybe. I dont know the cirucmstances of your system. You should give it a try and watch processing time etc. In fact, if you have to check an adress against the prefixes, for example to do something like a whitelisting, there is no option to check it. It could be interesting to test if regex-operations are faster here than converting the "regex-adresses" to normal adresses and make a prefix-substring of your search item - you have to test it in your specific environment

Comment: Is the list static, or does it change a lot?

Comment: To match prefixes, you should be able to use a TreeSet<String> to represent your list of prefixes. Not as reg-ex's but as plain prefix strings (`"10.25.3."`). Then you use [floor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29) to find the "best" matching prefix and check if it actually is a prefix of the given string. Complexity is O(log(n)) where n is the number of prefixes in your list.

Comment: @ClasG Yes, it is static, rarely changes.

Comment: @JimmyB: Thanks, i will try it! I found TreeSet also, but didn't know about its floor method.

Comment: regex matching against string representation of ip addresses is extremely inefficient, both memory and cpu-wise. it is recommended to parse those addresses into a binary format first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this library](https://github.com/bolcom/com-bol-ip) that was originally part of the RIPE whois server to quickly find matches. It allows you to build a tree of ranges and navigates the tree in an extremely efficient manner.

Example:

```
    // create & populate whitelist/blacklist tree
    NestedIntervalMap<Ipv4Resource, Boolean> map = new NestedIntervalMap<>();
    map.put(Ipv4Interval.parse("192.168/19"), true);
    map.put(Ipv4Interval.parse("192.168.52.1"), false);
    map.put(Ipv4Interval.parse("0/0"), false);

    // lookup if incoming IP is allowed to connect
    boolean allow = map.findFirstLessSpecific(new Ipv4Interval(incomingSocket.getInetAddress()));
```